# Swift 4 iOS - Word Count from UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Trying to make a "word count" feature using Swift 4 iOS - UITextField. The following code is unable to print the .count for strings typed inside my UITextField.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        //INPUT BOX - for Word Count!
        let INPUT : UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 35, y: 200, width: 350, height:50))
            INPUT.placeholder = "Type Words separated with Spaces!"
            INPUT.font = UIFont.init(name:"times", size: 22)
            INPUT.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0x00 ,green:0xff, blue:0x00 ,alpha:1)
            self.view.addSubview(INPUT)

        //variable holding the value of text typed
        let strings : String! = INPUT.text

        //variable holding the methods for detecting spaces and new lines
        let spaces = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.union(.punctuationCharacters)

        //variable storing the amount of words minus the spaces
        let words = strings.components(separatedBy: spaces)

        //method to display the word count in the console
        print(words.count)
    }
}
```

This error is being printed in the console: 
        "Result" => : 0

Comment: what does happen? is there and error or is the count 0?

Comment: This error is being printed in the console:
    "Result" => <int64: 0x608000231f60>: 0

Comment: But thats right.. it should be 0 at that location. I tried your code and added my answer. It then prints 2.

Comment: then it works fine, you just have to add a target for the event the text changes. And in the targeted function you count the words and print the result.

Comment: Thanks, Adarkas2302!  :) That worked! 
I just added the 'editingChanged' action to the UITextField :

INPUT.addTarget(self, action: #selector(WordCount), for: .editingChanged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your textview has no text in it at that point.

Try this:

```
INPUT.text = "Some Text"
```

Do get the text from an actual input:

```
INPUT.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let strings : String! = INPUT.text
    let spaces = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.union(.punctuationCharacters)
    let words = strings.components(separatedBy: spaces)
    print(words.count)

}
```

Comment: Jonas, the issue is detecting text when a user types into the UITextField.  Currently, the .count property does not detect an integer amount for separated string values from the INPUT.text after typing inside the UITextField.  Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Then show the position where you try to read it. In you example code it cant print something because the is nothing

Comment: @ctaylorgraphics all the codes remains in `viewDidLoad`. Are there `UITextFieldDelegate` methods that prints words count?

Comment: sCha, I have not included other methods to get the data from the UITextField once it is changed.  

I will create an 'editingChanged' action for the UITextField to execute a method to print words.count value.

Comment: now i understand your problem. You want to know how to print the wordcount after something changed in your Textview? I edited my answer. Hope this helps. Your question was confusing because you said it won`t work but it did!

Comment: Thanks so much, Jonas!  I added the following 'editingChanged' action to execute the method:  

INPUT.addTarget(self, action: #selector(WordCount), for: .editingChanged)